# How to toggle the case of letters in C?

Tags: c

My program should toggle the cases of some letters in some given strings.
For example, if the inputs are:

```
3
hELLo wOrld
hellO wORLD
HelLO WORLd
```

it must output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

but it does not.
I've tried everything I could and it still does not output the correct answers.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_len(char mystring[])
{
  int i, len = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 1001; i++)
  {
    if (mystring[i] != '\0')
    {
      len += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}

char upper_to_lower(char character)
{
    if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z')
    {
        return character - 'A' + 'a';
    }
    return character;
}

char lower_to_upper(char character)
{
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
    {
        return character - 'a' + 'A';
    }
    return character;
}

int main()
{
    char list[10][1000];
    int i, count;
    scanf("%d\n", &count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        char temp[1000];
        gets(temp);
        strcpy(list[i], temp);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //char f_temp[1000];
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < my_len(list[i]); j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                printf("%c", upper_to_lower(list[i][j]));
                //f_temp[j] = lower_to_upper(list[i][j]);
            }
            else if (list[i][j-1] != ' ')
            {
                printf("%c", upper_to_lower(list[i][j]));
                //f_temp[j] = upper_to_lower(list[i][j]);
            }
            else if (list[i][j-1] == ' ')
            {
                printf("%c", upper_to_lower(list[i][j]));
                //f_temp[j] = lower_to_upper(list[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //puts(f_temp);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The codes in the comments was another approach I tried to take, but it also did not help.
Any help would be appreciated.
(Note: I'm new to C, and I cannot use the string header for some reasons.)

Comment: The best way to debug is to use a debugger or even just add more debug print statements. There's a lot more debugging you can do on your own before resorting to asking for help on SO. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). One big problem is that `my_len` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You have other problems. But that is the main one. For example, you never call `lower_to_upper` but I don't know whether that is intentional at this stage of your dev/testing. Also, your logic in `main` is much more complex than it needs to be. Your last two cases do exactly the same thing in the body which doesn't seem to make sense. I advise you to go off and use the debugger now. Detailed debugging via SO is not productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of cleaning:

```
size_t my_len(const char *mystring)
{
    char *end = mystring;
    while(*end++);

    return end - mystring - 1;
}

int upper_to_lower(int character)
{
    if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z')
    {
        character = character + ('a' - 'A');
    }
    return character;
}

int lower_to_upper(int character)
{
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
    {
        character = character - ('a' - 'A');
    }
    return character;
}

char *mytolowerString(char *str)
{
    char *tmp = str;
    while(*str)
    {
        *str = upper_to_lower(*str);
        str++;
    }
    return tmp;
}

char *mytoupperString(char *str)
{
    char *tmp = str;
    while(*str)
    {
        *str = lower_to_upper(*str);
        str++;
    }
    return tmp;
}


int main()
{
    char z[] = "aSdFg345345345%&^%%ASD";
    char x[] = "aSdFg345345345%&^%%ASD";

    printf("%s \n%s\n", mytolowerString(z), mytoupperString(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` is missing in `my_len`. Need `return len;` as the last statement in that function.

Answer (score 2):

The is a trick that will work with ASCII characters:

```
int toggleCase(int c) {
    return c ^ ('A' ^ 'a');
}
```

The explanation is that ASCII code for 'A' is 65 and for 'a' is 97.
It means that the distance between UPPERCASE letters and lowercase letters is 32.
Thus flipping 5th bit will do the trick.

Comment: Here is a trick that works with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) : `return c ^ ('A' ^ 'a');`.  Toggle the bit(s) that differentiate upper and lower case.  No magic numbers.  Somewhat self-documenting.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks! Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `my_len` you do not return with `len`.
2. In `if (list[i][j-1] == ' ')` and `j == 0` cases you should use `lower_to_upper` function.